# dockerでanaconda3をダウンロードしたが、pip3が使えない

Tags: python3, docker-for-mac

macOS Sierra(10.12.6)を使用しております。
dockerでanaconda3のイメージをダウンロードしましたが、pip3がインストールされていないようです。
python3の環境でも、pipでライブラリをインストールしても問題ないのでしょうか？
pip3を使用しなければいけない場合、pip3のインストール方法をお教えいただけますと幸いです。
（BeautifulSoupやtensorflowをインストールしたいと考えております）

```
$pip -V
pip 9.0.1 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)

$pip3 -V
bash: pip3: command not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pip3は、Python2.x系とPython3.x系が共存している場合に、明示的にPython3.x系のモジュールをインストールするために使います。
今回はPython3.x系しか入っていない（有効になっていない）なら、pipコマンドで問題ないと思います。

Comment: 今回はPython3しか使用していないので問題なさそうです。ありがとうございました！